# Using analytics in sencha touch app

Tags: extjs, google-analytics, sencha-touch, analytics

I am new to sencha and i would like know which is the best way to use analytics in my sencha touch mobile app.

My app is just like a website, user can browse it from their browser. So it is not bunded into any apk or ipa file.

Please provide some suggestions to implement analytics in sencha app..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following components:

[Ext.ux.Analytics](https://github.com/ahj/Ext.ux.Analytics)
[ExtJS.ux.GoogleAnalytics](https://github.com/jmcriffey/ExtJS.ux.GoogleAnalytics)

Comment: Thanks.. Which is the best to use. Is it Google Analytics or Kissmetrics?

Comment: Kissmetrics isn't free, try analythic

Comment: is it possible to get the location , resolution , os version of my device using analytics ?

Comment: can't because I haven't!